# python Executing base class functions throw error

Tags: python

By referring to many online examples, I have tried to implement inheritance in python3.
 Here, I'm trying to use the parent class function and set the class variables in child class.

```
class adapter():
    def __init__(mem):
        mem.port=27017
        mem.ins='172.36.36.1'
        mem.klust=False
        mem.net=True
        mem.encryption=False
    def mKonnect(mem):
        eaeIns=mem.ins+':'+str(mem.port)
        return mClient(eaeIns)

class Fuse(adapter):
    mongoConnect=super(Fuse,mem).mKonnect()
    dbi=mongoConnect.eaedw.InstanceConfiguration
```

Whilst importing this module I get the below error:

> ```
> mongoConnect=super(Fuse,self).mKonnect()
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'Fuse' is not defined

I could not understand the mistake or is this not the way of coding for my requirement?

Comment: why do you use `mem` instead of `self`?

Comment: no particular reason, I read in docs that self can be renamed. So, just trying. Shouldn't I use?

Comment: I think the reason why you get the error is that you have to do it inside a member function, which you are missing. About the `mem` vs `self`, I just find it quite confusing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use super() a a class attribute declaration like you want to do.

It can work in the `__init__` method, but you need to define what `self` or `mem` is inside your class.

```
class Fuse(adapter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fuse, self).__init__()
        mongoConnect=super(Fuse,self).mKonnect()
        dbi=mongoConnect.eaedw.InstanceConfiguration
```

or even

```
class Fuse(adapter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fuse, self).__init__()
        dbi=self.mKonnect().eaedw.InstanceConfiguration
```

(You can rename `self` but that's not meaning you should do it, there are some conventions in Python, self is better if you want someone else to read and understand your code easily)

Comment: now the import succeeds but fails when accessing the objects: import mymodule as d; dd=d.Fuse() ; Error  eaeIns=self.ins+':'+str(self.port)
AttributeError: 'Fuse' object has no attribute 'ins'

Comment: @NNandu i omited to add `super(Fuse, self).__init__()` in the constructor, that's should solve this problem

Comment: @NNandu i think i made things more complicated than they are, you could call `mongoConnect = self.mKonnect()`  or even `dbi = self.mKonnect().eaedw.InstanceConfiguration` directly, after using `super(Fuse, self).__init__()`